# W2500 Wireless Keyboard Mouse set not working correclty on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: keyboard, asus

So question is pretty simple, i just bought the ASUS W2500 Wireless keyboard mouse set, mouse is working just fine, while keyboard not fully, it's working in BIOS but while ubuntu is booted only Super(Windows) Key and Media keys are working, are there any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this driver for [asus_wireless_keyboard](https://github.com/mikhail-matrosov/asus_wireless_keyboard)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.